# How do I control the page margins when streaming html as Microsoft Word

Tags: php, ms-word

I need to output a MS Word document through my web application, and I am utilizing the trick of streaming html with the content type set to application/vnd.msword.  This is working well however I am unable to figure out how to set the page margins in the resulting Word document.  They are coming out as 1 inch and I would like them to be smaller.

I'm using the technique documented here:
http://cosninix.com/wp/2010/04/generating-microsoft-office-documents-word-excel-on-your-webserver-using-php/

Comment: Create a real word document. There are php tools for this

Comment: I have actually been using PHPWord for many years, but it's becoming cumbersome to maintain both html layout and the PHPWord specific layout.  I was hoping to just use HTML.  Also, I need to be able to format some text as boldface and PHPWord isn't dealing with that nicely.

Comment: well calling html word, and hoping it will work is a guaranteed way to fail

Comment: thanks for the advice, but it's actually working for everything except the margins, so I feel it's still a good solution for a majority of use cases... I also don't feel that my hope had anything to do with the failure, it's probably a technical issue that has nothing to do with the hope I had.